# Как сверстать горизонтальное меню?

Tags: html, css, css3

Вот макет

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сверстать такое меню?

Comment: А в чём у вас проблема?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ну можно так

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1170px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.menu__inner {
  display: flex;
  background: gray;
  padding: 2px;
}

.menu__item {
  width: 25%;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.menu__item:hover {
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="menu__inner">
      <div class="menu__item">Административные здания</div>
      <div class="menu__item">Жилые здания</div>
      <div class="menu__item">Многофункциональные комплексы</div>
      <div class="menu__item">Общественные здания</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: А если .menu__item будет неизвестное количество то какой там будет width: ?

Comment: @Denis, `menu__inner` добавляете `justify-content: space-between;`, а `menu__item` добавляете `width: 100%;`

Answer (score 5):

На flex'ах свой ответ уже дали, дам и на grid'ах.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1170px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.container ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: grid;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 2px;
  grid-gap: 2px;
  height: 45px;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.container ul.mb-0 {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.container ul.auto-flow-column {
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}
.container ul.grid-col-1 {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
}
.container ul.grid-col-2 {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}
.container ul.grid-col-3 {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}
.container ul.grid-col-4 {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
}
.container ul.grid-col-5 {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
}
.container ul.grid-col-6 {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
}
.container ul.grid-col-7 {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 1fr);
}
.container ul.grid-col-8 {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 1fr);
}
.container ul.grid-col-9 {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(9, 1fr);
}
.container ul.grid-col-10 {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(10, 1fr);
}
.container ul li {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.container ul li a {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.container ul li a:hover, .container ul li a.active {
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <nav>
  <h1>Не явно указываем размер одного элемента</h1>
  <ul class="auto-flow-column mb-0">
   <li>
    <a href="#!">Административные здания</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="auto-flow-column mb-0">
   <li>
    <a href="#!">Административные здания</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="#!">Жилые здания</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="auto-flow-column mb-0">
   <li>
    <a href="#!">Административные здания</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="#!">Жилые здания</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="#!">Многофункциональные комплексы</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="auto-flow-column mb-0">
   <li>
    <a href="#!">Административные здания</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="#!">Жилые здания</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="#!">Многофункциональные комплексы</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="#!">Общественные здания</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="auto-flow-column">
   <li>
    <a href="#!">Административные здания</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="#!">Жилые здания</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="#!">Многофункциональные комплексы</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="#!">Общественные здания</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="#!">Другое названиe</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
  
  <h1>Явно указываем размер одного элемента</h1>
  <ul class="grid-col-1 mb-0">
   <li>
    <a href="#!">Административные здания</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="grid-col-2 mb-0">
   <li>
    <a href="#!">Административные здания</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="#!">Жилые здания</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="grid-col-3 mb-0">
   <li>
    <a href="#!">Административные здания</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="#!">Жилые здания</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="#!">Многофункциональные комплексы</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="grid-col-4 mb-0">
   <li>
    <a href="#!">Административные здания</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="#!">Жилые здания</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="#!">Многофункциональные комплексы</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="#!">Общественные здания</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="grid-col-5 mb-0">
   <li>
    <a href="#!">Административные здания</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="#!">Жилые здания</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="#!">Многофункциональные комплексы</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="#!">Общественные здания</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="#!">Другое названиe</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
</div>
```

Если вам нужны одинаковые блоки - задаём количество явно, через grid-col-(число)

Если нет, просто auto-flow-column и стили соответствующие.

Если не влезает, конечно же можно задать и перенос, но это уже явно вне этого вопроса.

Люблю гриды из-за их gap'a и лёгкой адаптивности.

Исходник: [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qLzchyg0/) (там SASS)

Answer (score 4):

На flex'ах и grid'ах ответ дали, дам на `display: inline-block`;

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.menu {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.menu::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.menu > .item {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: calc(100% / 4);
  /* 4 - кол-во элементов в меню*/
  padding: 8px 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #ccc;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: '..';
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu > .item:hover {
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <div class="item">Административные здания</div>
  <div class="item">Жилые здания</div>
  <div class="item">Многофункциональные комплексы</div>
  <div class="item">Общественные здания</div>
</div>
```